# Eliminar elemento de un string JS

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo la siguiente cadena

```
[{"idServicio":10},{"idServicio":11},{"idServicio":12}]
```

y lo que quiero hacer es eliminar un elemento a partir del valor del idServicio, por ejemplo eliminando el id de valor 11, y quede algo asi:

```
[{"idServicio":10},{"idServicio":12}]
```

Podría ayudarme del método `substr` pero quería saber si existe un método o función al que le pase el valor del id y lo elimine en una sola linea de código, sin preocuparse por la ubicación del elemento y las comas.

> Para mi es un JSON, pero la consola de JS me dice que es un string
>   (podrá ser ambos?) por eso el titulo de la pregunta es asi. Si tengo
>   errados los conceptos agradezco cualquier comentario, estoy dando mis
>   primeros pasos.

Muchas gracias

Comment: estas haciendo parse de los datos cuando mandas el request (suponiendo que viene de un request) ?

Comment: Le paso los datos con un JSON.stringify(string). Después en otra función voy a guardar estos datos en una variable, con JSON.parse, pero para cuando llegue a esa altura del código quiero haber podido eliminar lo que sea necesario.

Comment: te llega algo así ? `'[{"idServicio":10},{"idServicio":11},{"idServicio":12}]'`, si es el caso debes hacer un JSON.parse()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes auxiliarte del método `filter()` el cual:

**Edición**

Necesitas hacer uso de `JSON.parse()` puesto que al inicio tienes una cadena de textoy con dicho método obtendremos un objeto de JavaScript que será susceptible de ser iterado por el método que estoy proponiendo en esta *respuesta*

Va a permitirte generar un nuevo vector con los elementos del vector original que cumplan una determinada condición.

Por ejemplo en tu escenario, puedes: Filtrar por la clave `idServicio` cuando esta misma sea diferente a 11, de modo que la variable `datos` se convierta en el nuevo vector que tiene todos los elementos del anterior menos aquel de id 11

Quedando así:

```js
    data = '[{"idServicio":10},{"idServicio":11},{"idServicio":12}]'
    data2 = JSON.parse(data)
        
    let datos = data2.filter((elemento) => elemento.idServicio !== 11)
        
    console.log(datos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Que tal te dejo esta función, espero te sirva:

`splice` es el encargado de borrar el objeto encontrado:

**1º** parámetro: borrará el objeto de índice i.
**2º** parámetro: borra el nº de objetos, en nuestro caso solo 1.
**3º** parámetro opcional permite además añadir.

```js
 
 function eliminarElemento(ids){
 
//Borrar un objeto concreto del array:
for (var i =0; i < ids.length; i++){
   if (ids[i].idServicio === 11) {
      ids.splice(i,1);
   }
}
return JSON.stringify(ids);

}

let ids = [{"idServicio":10},{"idServicio":11},{"idServicio":12}];

console.log(eliminarElemento(ids));
```